# how to invoke methods of type "LIST" in java

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using reflection in java. It is trouble how do I invoke methods of a class which is of type `List`. For example,

File called `PurchaseOrder` has one List element.
`List<LineItem> lineitem;`

`LineItem` is a file which has again elements which have names and return types. How can I invoke methods dynamically using reflection?

Below is hardcoding for the same for reference.

```
PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder();
List<LineItem> lt = po.getLineItem();    
lt.add(newItem);
```

Do help. I appreciate if any of you suggest an idea.

Comment: Idea for what? There are at least two questions here.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but this is [how you call a method using reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Comment: i am able to get the name of method for a file "PurchaseOrder" and that is getLineItem(). so i need dynamic code for line 2 and 3.

Comment: Which methods on which class? Why do you need reflection - where are the method names coming from and to which classes/objects do they refer? I'm afraid the question as it stands is a bit confused which makes it unanswerable :(

Comment: What do you mean by the "file" PurchaseOrder? In the above it is a class. Are you saying you have a String with the text "PurchaseOrder" and want to instantiate the class PurchaseOrder?

Comment: Adrian, i have to build dynamic code to set the elements of XSD. I am using JAXB framework. so reflection is only option to do the same.

Comment: yaah adrian. Everything i have is in a string form. I load the class ""PurchaseOrder" to get the methods of its class using Class.forName("PurchaseOrder") method

Comment: You're dynamically creating an XSD file? I'm not sure that's a great idea. I'm afraid I still really don't understand the question.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you read the article linked by assylias and come back when you have a more specific issue.

Comment: wait adrian i make you understand about project i am working on. I am parsing XSD file using JAXB framework. After parsing I have java classes for elements of ComplexType. To set data to all its elements i need methods basically setter methods. so i pass classname as string in class.forName() method and setting its elmenets dynamically. I am not able to understand for elements which is of type List as discussed in question.

Comment: make me understand to dynamically generate coding for the this.......
List<LineItem> lt = po.getLineItem();

Comment: I'm sorry, you've really lost me. If you have managed to create po, you can just directly call the method...

Comment: look adrian. am writing coding which fulfills first line.....Class class = Class.forName("PurchaseOrder");
Object classObject = class.newInstance();..........but for 2nd statement, please help me

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see.

I've never done this but I think it will look something like:

```
Class class = Class.forName("PurchaseOrder"); 
Object classObject = class.newInstance();
Method toInvoke = class.getMethod("getLineItem");
Object ret = toInvoke.invoke(classObject);
```

I hope that gets you started.

Comment: hey adrian i have done this earlier and working correctly. help me doin the same for line 2.

Comment: Again, I'm afraid I don't follow. The last two lines are the equivalent of "List<LineItem> lt = po.getLineItem();" You can then cast the result to List<LineItem> and repeat the getMethod and invoke steps to call "add".

Comment: yaah adrian, thst is the point where i have been stuck in. i do not get this how to do that

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to do this all for you. It really should be fairly easy following the above pattern.

Comment: Actually, you won't need to cast: just do ret.getClass().getMethod... Also, shouldn't getLineItem be getLineItem*s* or similar? I'm surprised it returns a list rather than a single object.